# c# Object parameter mysteriously cleared after assigned a parameter

Tags: c#, list, point, mouseup

I am a newbie to C#. I want to collect all the points for a Paint action in `MouseUp` event. After I pass in the parameters from `aPaintAction2` into `Actions2`, I clear the content of `aPaintAction2`. Somehow, after the `aPaintAction2` content is cleared, the parameter value in `Actions2` (that `aPaintAction2` passed in) is also cleared.

Can someone explain to me what is this problem and why is this happening? I just want to pass in the points `aPaintAction2` holds into `Actions2`, `Actions2` keeps the points parameters, and clear `aPaintAction2` so that `aPaintAction2` can hold new points. Thank you.

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (moving && x != -1 && y != -1)
        {
            aPaintAction2.Add(e.Location);
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private List<AnnotationAction> Actions2 = new List<AnnotationAction>();
    private List<Point> aPaintAction2 = new List<Point>();
    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // save a Paint action
        Actions2.Add(new AnnotationAction(newActionId, pen.Color, pen.Width, aPaintAction2));

        aPaintAction2.Clear();

        moving = false;
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
        newActionId++;
    }
```

Comment: The value of `aPaintAction2` is just a *reference* to the list. Both your `AnnotationAction` and `aPaintAction2` will have a reference to the same list. See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html for more details

Comment: just clone  aPaintAction2  and than add it .

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading a good book or tutorial at this point. It's *really* important that you understand how reference types work in .NET, or you'll get really confused. (Note that my article isn't trying to provide guidelines, just information.)

Comment: @GauravMoolani how to clone it?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you JonSkeet. As I have self low-esteem I tend to delete reply that sounds stupid... haha.. After reading your link several times, I understood the difference between value type and reference type. But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @Min there are two ways to clone . Serialize and deserialize and other is expression tree. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-by-Expression-Trees-C-Sharp.  Expression tree is faster and takes less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
aPaintAction2.Clear();
```

which removes all items from the list, try:

```
aPaintAction2 = new List<Point>();
```

which will create a new empty list, but leave the old list in the Actions.